# Using arbitary number / signature to enable Social Recovery using Auth Kit of Safe

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I  hope you are doing well. I am making an Wallet here I am going to generate a Nullifier hash of each user Aadhar Card (It is an Identity Card of Indian Citizens). I am looking to use Safe Auth Kit to enable social recovery feature where I am looking to enable social recovery using the Provides Nullifier Hash.

Thus I have question Is it Possible to do that and If Yes. How can I build that feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer, yes it should be possible to create your own [Safe module](https://docs.safe.global/safe-smart-account/modules) to handle recovery, using the business logic you like. I don't know what implementation details would make more sense, but for reference we recently deployed a [Recovery mechanism](https://safe-global.notion.site/Safe-RecoveryHub-Technical-Deep-dive-e5c1d70c2cc34d70adcbf4023d383a7e?pvs=4) on Safe{Wallet} and are looking into making it more accessible as a Safe module (however this is a work in progress).

In the meantime, you can also look at [other implementations](https://forum.safe.global/t/social-recovery-module/2117) from the community for inspirations.

Hope it helps,
Louis